# Is it possible to offset dynamic styles set through jquery in just css?

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a jquery function which is adding inline styles to one of my divs.

```
element.style {width:100px;height:100px;top:100px}
```

etc.

The element style is dynamic, depending on brower size, position of view port etc.

What I need to do is add an offset to those styles, for example adding an extra 10px to width or -50px from top.

I can't just use important like this

```
element.style {width:110px!important;height:100px;top:50px!important}
```

Because the style will be different on each browser/device etc.

The difficult way is to copy the entire jquery library for that function and add the offset through jquery.

But was wondering whether there could be an easier way to just say to the div add an extra 10px to this style or remove 50px from this style?.

Comment: If you know it's a defined set of styling, then why not put it against a class and use the jquery to toggle the classs?

Comment: `Because the style will be different on each browser/device etc.` Why? That's not good practice as it makes things more complicated to amend - exactly as in this case. It sounds like you should be using media queries to update the UI based on screen size, then adding/removing classes as necessary as @AndrewCorrigan pointed out

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes its a very old jquery library on an old install. It's best to just remove and replace with more modern but not able to right now. 
The jquery dynamically loads the div positions it on the page. The div position is set using parameters like width, height, top, left. etc. As its dynamic this position will be different everytime its called so I can't just add a class and set my own parameters, unless I can do something like adding an offset to what is being set in the element style.

Answer (score 0):

Please do what the comments have said. If you really need to do this your way, you could do it like this:

Give your element an ID first, then:

```
function changeStyle() {
    var currentHeight = parseInt($("#element-id").css("height"));
    $("#element-id").css("height", currentHeight + 10 + "px");
}
```

You can look at this example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/krzq87p3/3/

jQuery `.css()` docs: https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2